# StructureMap: Concrete class constructor accepts multiple arguments of same interface type

Tags: c#, interface, structuremap

I want to use StructureMap ObjectFactory to handle the instantiation of my classes used by my WCF service. While my limited experience is sufficient to handle the simple 1:1 mappings between one interface and that one, single class that implements it, I've hit a snag where a constructor accepts multiple parameters of the same interface.

I reckon I can associate multiple concrete classes to the same interface by giving each mapping a name, but how do I tell StructureMap what mapping to use for the first and the second constructor parameter?

This is the class I want ObjectFactory to handle for me:

```
public class MasterPolicy {
    public MasterPolicy(IPolicy alfaPolicy, IPolicy numericPolicy)
    {
        AlphaPolicy = alphaPolicy;
        NumericPolicy = numericPolicy;
    }

    public IPolicy AlphaPolicy {get; private set; }
    public IPolicy NumericPolicy {get; private set; }

    public bool IsValid(string s)
    {
         if (!AlphaPolicy.IsValid(s)) return false;
         if (!NumericPolicy.IsValid(s)) return false;
         return true;
    }
}
```

The IPolicy interface is implemented by more than one class:

```
public interface IPolicy
{
    bool IsValid(string s);
}

public class AlphaPolicy : IPolicy
{
    public bool IsValid(string s) { return true; }
}

public class NumericPolicy : IPolicy
{
    public bool IsValid(string s) { return true; }
}
```

(Of course, MasterPolicy could too implement the IPolicy interface).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify constructor dependencies and tell structure map which named argument should have which dependency:

```
For<MasterPolicy>.Use<MasterPolicy>()
    .Ctor<IPolicy>("alphaPolicy").Is<AlphaPolicy>()
    .Ctor<IPolicy>("numericPolicy").Is<NumericPolicy>();
```

Comment: Thanks! This was just what I needed to get a better grasp of StructureMap.

Comment: that makes MAster Policy Class tightly coupled to the Container , don't you think so ?

Comment: @Kevorkian - `MasterPolicy` has no references at all to the container, so I don't see how it can have any coupling to the container. The container is going to have control coupling to all classes it's bootstrapping/composing.

Comment: @PHeiberg  what i mean is , what will happen if i change the MasterPolicy Constructor's Signature , something like:  `public MasterPolicy(IPolicy APolicy, IPolicy NPolicy)
    {
        AlphaPolicy = alphaPolicy;
        NumericPolicy = numericPolicy;
    }`  Another Question , what will happen if change the order of params during a new initialisation ?

Comment: @Kevorkian - Since there are two arguments with the same type, we need to specify the names of the arguments, which makes it brittle. If the names of the arguments are changed the Ctor config will need to be changed as well. Order doesn't matter as long as the names are correct.